# Unbounded Operator not bounded on any ball

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dual-spaces

I came across a small proof where the following implication was used:

Let $X$ be a normed v.s. and    $T \in X'$ an unbounded operator ( $X'$ denotes the dual of $X$ ), i.e.

$$  \| T (x) \| \gt M \| x \| \qquad \forall M >0, x \in X $$

then

$$ \sup_{ \| x \| \le \epsilon } \| T(x) \| \gt M \qquad \forall \epsilon >0, M >0 $$

How do I see this? I tried using linearity to reshape the supremum condition, but I cannot clearly reason why this implication is true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something is wrong. Your hypothesis does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe if I cite exactly what is said in proof, you can tell me what exactly does not make sense: 
Let T be unbounded and fix epsilon. then for any a, we can find y in B(0, epsilon) such that Ty = b and |b| > |a|. 
I wrote in my notes that this results from the fact that the operator is unbounded on any ball, but I somehow cannot see why.

Comment: For the question in the title use: $Tx=\epsilon T( \frac x {\epsilon }) $

Comment: The inequality $\sup_{\| x \| \le 1} \| T (x) \| \gt M \| x \|$ makes no sense. (It's also totally different from the citation you give in a comment...)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question so the question does make sense now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sup_{\|x\|\le\epsilon}\|T(x)\|=M<\infty$, since $T(x)=T(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \epsilon x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} T(\epsilon x)$, whenever $\|x\|\le 1$, we must have $\|\epsilon x\|\le \epsilon$, $\|T(x)\|\le \frac{1}{\epsilon} M<\infty$.